# How do we redirect to a cross domain URL from a Mule 4 application?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm trying to redirect to an external website URL using Mule 4 application but only endpoint is changing keeping the same (old page) domain. But I need to change the endpoint along with external domain.

I am using HTTP request connector for doing that.

Here is some of our XML code:

```
 <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="14a8eee1-b907-4306-86da-d46eee402a56" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="partners.checkr.com" port="443" />
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="OAuth2Flow" doc:id="fedc6c32-82fa-4e7d-bc4a-6425daf0642c" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="157b2a3d-ea31-4496-9808-b2b43058cccd" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="0502ced7-b52d-4f64-aee1-ed3525998fed" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/" followRedirects="true"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Redirect should happen in such a way that entire URL should be redirect ( domain + end point).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you have 'forgotten' to actually include the XML code you mention.

Answer (score 1):

To completely redirect them to a different domain and leave your mule app, you can set a 302 status and a Location header:

```
<flow name="OAuth2Flow" doc:id="2e0b1fe9-0d1f-48a1-9d35-d272509de426" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="45692a0f-8c10-47c3-8b26-5bb9e7a715d5" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/">
            <http:response statusCode="302" >
                <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "Location" : "https://partners.checkr.com/"
}]]]></http:headers>
            </http:response>
        </http:listener>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="66629470-b152-498d-9a37-801873348698" />
    </flow>
```